# javascript: запись значения в ассоциативный массив в одну строку

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть такой код:

```
    let tmp: any = this.state.states;
    tmp[event.target.id] = event.target.checked;

    this.setState({
        states: tmp
    });
```

Подскажите, как бы в 1 строчку покрасивее сформировать tmp массив, т.е. что-то типа

```
    this.setState({
        states: [...this.state.states, event.target.id: event.target.checked]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как бы в 1 строчку покрасивее сформировать tmp массив, т.е. что-то типа

Так и запиши...

```
this.setState(old => {
    return {...old.states, [event.target.id]: event.target.checked}
});
```

Или так

```
this.setState(old => ({...old.states, [event.target.id]: event.target.checked}));
```

Тест

```js
let obj = {'xxx': 10, 'yyy': 11}
obj = {...obj, 'yyy': 12}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: т.е. если у меня есть объект `obj = {'xxx': 10, 'yyy': 11}`, то по сути мне надо сделать так: `obj = {...obj, ['yyy']: 12}`?

Comment: @Zhihar, да. И даже скобки не нужно ставить - `obj = {...obj, 'yyy': 12}`. См.ответ, я там дописал тест. ;)